# Laravel authentication throwing weird error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.deleted_at'
in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user` where `user`.`deleted_at` is
null and `username` = john limit 1)
```

So I am sending the following data to my login route: `username=john&password=test`

But when I execute the following code in my **routes.php** I get the error show above.

```
Route::post('login', function()
{
    $credentials = array(
        "username" => Input::get("username"),
        "password" => Input::get("password")
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
    }
    else {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }

});
```

The thing that bothers me is that I don't have `deleted_at` column in my user table and I don't know why laravel need to this column in my table when all I am doing is trying to login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The thing that bothers me is that I don't have deleted_at column in my user table

Yes, the error message is complaining about that.

> I don't know why laravel need to this column in my table when all I am doing is trying to login.

Your User model likely has [soft deletion](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting) enabled. Look for `$softDelete` in your `User.php` file in the `app/models` folder and set it to false, or add the column if you want soft deletions.

Comment: So does this mean when I create the User table using migration, I need to add the deleted_at column manually?

Comment: Per the migration docs, `$table->softDeletes();` adds that column in a migration.

Comment: Okay, looks like I need to RTFM. Thanks a lot. I added a new migration with `$table->softDeletes();` just like you said and it worked! Thanks a million!

Comment: In your model file (probably `User.php`) remove the softdeletes trait, this line: `use SoftDeletes;`